# NotImplementedError: Traceback (most recent call last): <ipython-input-54-87754d21578b> in <module>

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know lots of people have asked question about "NotImplementedError". However, after I looking through the existing answers, I still do not understand how to fix it in my situation.

**My purpose is getting the top 15 countries for average GDP over the last 10 years**

The `Newdata3` dataframe is looked like below
[image]

**Created a new column**

```
Newdata3['avgGDP']=(Newdata3['2006']+Newdata3['2007']+Newdata3['2008']+Newdata3['2009']+Newdata3['2010']+Newdata3['2011']+Newdata3['2012']+Newdata3['2013']+Newdata3['2014']+Newdata3['2015'])/10
```

**Sorted in descending order**

```
Newdata3 = Newdata3.sort_values(by=['avgGDP'], ascending=False)
```

**Converted Pandas DataFrame to a Series**

`ans = Newdata3['avgGDP']`
`ans2 = ans.squeeze()`

**Wrote down the answer**

```
def answer_three():
    ans2= ans.squeeze()
    return ans2
raise NotImplementedError()
```

**And then I received error**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-87754d21578b> in <module>
      4     return ans2
      5 
----> 6 raise NotImplementedError()

NotImplementedError:
```

**And for this exercise, they have a check requirement, I failed this as well. But I thought I already transform to a series?**

```
assert type(answer_three()) == pd.Series, "Q3: You should return a Series!"
```

[image]

Comment: looks like you're raising the error yourself for no reason with `raise NotImplementedError()`?

Comment: @ShubhamPeriwal Hey, but ```raise NotImplementedError() ``` is the original coding content given by the exercise, which I should not delete?

Comment: If that is the case, then it's possible you're using it incorrectly. Maybe they used it under certain conditions. For example : `If xxx then raise error`. In your case it's just going to raise every single time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have raised the error by yourself in the code by writing the below line.

```
raise NotImplementedError()
```

After the execution of function named "answer_three" `raise NotImplementedError()` executed which raises an error.

Remove this line if you don't want to raise an error.

`assert` keyword is used when debugging code. The assert keyword lets you test if a condition in your code matched returns True, if not, the program will raise an `AssertionError`

```
assert type(answer_three()) == pd.Series, "Q3: You should return a Series!"
```

In the above line the it's checking if the return type of the function named `answer_three()` is `pd.series` then return true (do nothing) else raise an `AssertionError`

Comment: But this is the original coding content given by the exercise, which I should not delete?

Comment: Basically `NotImplemented`  is an exception which is raised by the developer when the code or functionality in a code isn't completed. So maybe in your exercise the code is incomplete and supposed to be completed by you. So remove it when you achieve the required functionality..

Comment: Thank you for that. But then I meet the 2nd error said "You should return a Series!" But I thought I already transform to a 'series'?

Comment: Where is that? seems like an another problem which is in the code you have not provided in the question..

Comment: Thank you for your time. I just update the question. Would you mind see it again?